# My Css is not being rendered for the django rest framework access page but its being rendered for other webpages when using apache server

Tags: css, django, apache, django-rest-framework

The css gets rendered properly when I use the django development server I checked the static files and the required css files have been collected in the folder as well

Below is the apache server .conf file
me_buildout_xmeme is the repo name memev2 is the project name

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8080>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/django/me_buildout_xmeme
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
  Alias /static /home/ubuntu/django/me_buildout_xmeme/static 
  <Directory /home/ubuntu/django/me_buildout_xmeme/static> 
    Require all granted
  </Directory> 
  <Directory /home/ubuntu/django/me_buildout_xmeme/memev2> 
    <Files wsgi.py>  
      Require all granted
    </Files>    
  </Directory>   
  WSGIDaemonProcess memev2 python-path=/home/ubuntu/django/me_buildout_xmeme python-home=/home/ubuntu/django/myprojectenv
  WSGIProcessGroup memev2  
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/django/me_buildout_xmeme/memev2/wsgi.py 
</VirtualHost>
```

This refers to the settings.py settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'



STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_collected')

# STATIC_ROOT='static'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'




STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: Have you tried to clear your browser cache ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apache configuration is serving the `static` directory, but your `STATIC_ROOT` setting is set to `static-collected`. You need to serve the `static-collected` directory in apache.

Comment: but then it renders all other webpages

Comment: What do you mean by "all other webpages"?

Comment: Also im not able change the apache port to 8080 only 80 works using the conf file given above